# How can i make the light turn on and off by touching and not touching a sphere collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a game where i have a lightswitch, whenever i'm touching the spherecollider around the switch, the light should turn on. And when i'm not touching the spherecollider anymore, it should turn off. I've not been doing this in a long time, so i've gotten a bit rusty.

```
public Light ceilingLight;
public bool LS;

private void Update()
{
    if (LS == true)
    {
        ceilingLight.enabled = true;
    }
    if(LS == false)
    {
        ceilingLight.enabled = false;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        LS = true;
    }
    if(other.tag != "Player")
    {
        LS = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably wanted to turn it off ontriggerexit rahter than anythung else  maybe entered the trigger

Answer (score 0):

First: Instead of using `Update` you rather want it to be event driven and this avoid unnecessary `Update` calls when nothing changed anyway.

Then as was mentioned in the comment what you currently do is enable the light if the player touches, disable it if anything else touches it.

You rather want to disable it when the player doesn't touch anymore and ignore everything else.

Simply do

```
public Light ceilingLight;
// optionally additionally configure whether the light should start enabled or not
public bool InitiallyEnabled;

private void Start()
{
    ceilingLight.enabled = InitiallyEnabled;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;

    ceilingLight.enabled = true;
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if(!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;

    ceilingLight.enabled = false;
}
```

As alternative you could also use it as a toggle like

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;

    ceilingLight.enabled = ! ceilingLight.enabled;
}
```

so with every touch the player would toggle the light state without having to keep pressing it continuously.

Answer (score -1):

Consider that you may need all types of things to be pressable later on in your app, so you could start with a basic `Pressable` class to handle the basics. You can then add this behavior to the compositing mix of your respective prefab objects (which may be `Holdable`, `Steerable`, `Pressable` and so on):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Pressable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] protected bool active = false;
    [SerializeField] AudioSource pressSound = null;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
    }

    public virtual void Press()
    {
        if (pressSound != null) { pressSound.Play(); }

        active = !active;
    }

}
```

Note the `active` bool will appear in the inspector, so you can set it to `true` at start. (You may also want to pass `Press(Person person)` in case something should be done with the person pressing.)

Now for your specific light switch, you would inherit this and add the logic for just lights:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LightPressable : Pressable
{
    Light light = null;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        light = GetComponentInChildren<Light>();
        UpdateBasedOnActive();
    }

    public override void Press()
    {
        base.Press();

        UpdateBasedOnActive();
    }

    void UpdateBasedOnActive()
    {
        light.enabled = active;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is a nice explanation of abstraction but ... Why do you assume that the `Light` is a child of the responsible toggle? And this still doesn't solve/address how `Press` would be called here and in Ops specifoc case how the light should turn off when the player is not touching the collider anymore ... So this seems to be a good answer but to a different question ... ;)

Comment: You're right, I just hoped it might be of a related use. You gave a great pinpointed answer, and maybe this answer can be used for additional inspiration as how to structure the light pressing in general. (As for where the Light is, that could also be put into a SerializeField or so.)